# bringSubviewToFront not working when programmatically placing one ImageView on top of another in Swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to place one `UIImageView` on top of another as follows:

```
let seatView = SeatView();
let size = UIScreen.main.bounds;
let myimage : UIImage = UIImage(named:playerBoxName)!
let playerSeat = UIImageView(image: myimage);
let width = (size.width * seatWidthFactor) / size.width;
let height = (size.height * seatHeightFactor) / size.width;
seatView.frame =  CGRect(x:origin.x, y:origin.y, width: width, height: height);
let cardPairBackImage = UIImage(named:"cardDeck_2");
let cardPairBackImageView = UIImageView(image:cardPairBackImage);
cardPairBackImageView.frame = CGRect(x:origin.x + 40, y:origin.y+20, width: 20, height: 30);

seatView.addSubview(cardPairBackImageView);
seatView.sendSubviewToBack(cardPairBackImageView);
let playerNameLabel = PlayerLabel(frame:CGRect(x: 44, y: 2, width: 54, height: 12 ));
playerNameLabel.setProperties(borderWidth: 0, borderColor: CGColor.init(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0));
if !avatarName.contains("Empty") {
    playerNameLabel.text = "player";
    seatView.addSubview(playerNameLabel);
}
seatView.addSubview(playerSeat);
let avatarImage = UIImage(named:avatarName);
let avatarImageView = UIImageView(image:avatarImage);
seatView.addSubview(avatarImageView);
seatView.bringSubviewToFront(playerNameLabel);
```

This is the view hierarchy:

[image]

The `cardPairBackImage` always ends up on top of all subviews, but I want that to be pushed to the back of all views (images). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your problem might have something to do with the implementation of your SeatView class. Because that code and storyboard aren't part of your question, it's hard to know. Did you try using the same subview logic on a plain old UIView? Also, this is not a SwiftUI question, but UIKit...

Comment: I don't see anything indicating that the `cardPairBackImageView` is going to be on top of `playerNameLabel` or `avatarImageView` or `playerSeat`. How do you know this is the case? Can we see proof that this is so?

Comment: The resulting output on the screen shows cardPairBackImageView on top of all others.

Comment: See the output at 
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVgA6.png

Comment: The SeatView class is derived from a UIView.  What specifically, if anything do I need to implement in the SeatView class to make it work?  I am fairly new to Swift.

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything special: I asked about the SeatView implementation because it might be interfering with "normal" UIView behavior. When I use your code in a regular UIView, the card image goes to the back as expected. But as I said in my previous comment, there's a lot of information missing in your question. Where is the SeatView in your ViewController hierarchy, for example?

Comment: The controller calls let seatRenderer = SeatRenderer();  seatRenderer.render(view: self.view);  And in the render method I call:  let playerSeat = SeatView.Create(origin:origin, avatarName: avatar, playerBoxName: "rightPlayerBox")
        self.view.addSubview(playerSeat);     //view passed down from the controller to the SeatRenderer.

Comment: You can find a more detailed view of the hierarchy here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IO8SK.png

Comment: Also, you should do the same check `!avatarName.contains("Empty")` before calling `seatView.bringSubviewToFront(playerNameLabel)`

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that the method might not be working correctly since you haven't added all the views. What happens if you do this:

```
let seatView = SeatView();
let size = UIScreen.main.bounds;
let width = (size.width * seatWidthFactor) / size.width;
let height = (size.height * seatHeightFactor) / size.width;
seatView.frame =  CGRect(x:origin.x, y:origin.y, width: width, height: height);

let cardPairBackImage = UIImage(named:"cardDeck_2");
let cardPairBackImageView = UIImageView(image:cardPairBackImage);
cardPairBackImageView.frame = CGRect(x:origin.x + 40, y:origin.y+20, width: 20, height: 30);
seatView.addSubview(cardPairBackImageView);
//seatView.sendSubviewToBack(cardPairBackImageView);

let playerNameLabel = PlayerLabel(frame:CGRect(x: 44, y: 2, width: 54, height: 12 ));
playerNameLabel.setProperties(borderWidth: 0, borderColor: CGColor.init(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0));

if !avatarName.contains("Empty") {
    playerNameLabel.text = "player";
    seatView.addSubview(playerNameLabel);
}

let myimage : UIImage = UIImage(named:playerBoxName)!
let playerSeat = UIImageView(image: myimage);
seatView.addSubview(playerSeat);

let avatarImage = UIImage(named:avatarName);
let avatarImageView = UIImageView(image:avatarImage);
seatView.addSubview(avatarImageView);

//Try bringing only one view to the front after all the 
//subviews are added and the subviews array is populated
seatView.bringSubviewToFront(playerNameLabel);
```

Comment: I tried the above code.  There is no change in the output.

Comment: Interesting. Can you inspect the UI hierarchy using the [View Hierarchy Debugger](https://dmytro-anokhin.medium.com/overview-of-developer-tools-for-ui-debugging-122e4995f972) and show us what order the views are laid out in?

Comment: You can find the hierarchy here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bozC.png

Comment: Can you focus on one of the `seatView`?

Comment: You can see it here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IO8SK.png

Comment: What happens if you try: `playerNameLabel.superView.bringSubviewToFront(playerNameLabel)`

Comment: playerNameLabel is a UILabel, hence it has no superView.  The error displayed is 'Value of type 'UILabel' has no member 'superView' ' .

Comment: That's odd. :/ Do you have your code uploaded anywhere? Also, can you click on one of the `seatView` in view hierarchy debugger and show how that looks after you focus on it and the view hierarchy on the left side?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the code uploaded anywhere, and can't.

Comment: Is `seatView` not clickable in the view debugger?

Comment: It looks like : https://i.stack.imgur.com/pj5CQ.png

Comment: And what about the list of its view hierarchy on the left side of Xcode?

Comment: You can see it here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOxeG.png

Comment: Great! Thanks for sharing this. Now we will be able to see if `bringSubviewToFront` and `sendSubviewToBack` are having any effect or not. It's not good for debugging that it calls all the 3 images UIImage view.  But can you try calling `bringSubviewToFront` on something other than `playerNameLabel` and check if this order you saw changes?

Comment: Right now it is UIImageView, UIImageView, UIImageView, Label.

Comment: Are there any working examples of how you would overlay multiple images, one on top of the other?

Comment: I had tried different combinations, but currently I am calling  seatView.bringSubviewToFront(playerNameLabel);  This is second last line, before seatview is returned

Comment: I tried, as you suggested,  seatView.bringSubviewToFront(playerSeat);  It just pushes back label (not visible anymore), but the cards are still on top.

Comment: Hmm. This is strange. There are working examples. But the syntax is correct. Can you show me the view hierarchy for `seatView.bringSubviewToFront(playerSeat)`?

Comment: Is this something that could be solved with layering?

Comment: What is layering?

Comment: You can see them here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/13wYpiyECjFfPlwl0CF6Y1tEUsztBENzD/view?usp=sharing. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1d0eZGXbFsnnmh4i1TOky_c4WWvnXvdIE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Layering: https://www.appcoda.com/calayer-introduction/

Comment: Can you try setting the zPosition in the order you prefer like this: `view.layer.zPosition` = -20, -10 , etc?

Comment: Tried zPosition. No effect, I am afraid.

Comment: That sucks. Can you put your code on github?

Comment: Also, can you draw using paint or draw.io how you want the final output to look? Like the order of seat, card back, player, and player name?

Comment: The final output should look like https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-IQi9N7pQtBWaZOPhdYQIBAKeb34pKuw/view?usp=sharing.    If you can guide or give me an example it would be great.

Comment: I can't view any of your drive links can you make them public?

Comment: Try now with https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1xX-Kvnly4usdu7Ry3JqCkViKWuX_UCg0?usp=sharing

Comment: Hope it is accessible now.

Comment: Thanks. In the screenshot of player 3, it looks like everything is rendering properly. Now what is different for that perticular player?

Comment: Thanks. In the screenshot of player 3, it looks like everything is rendering properly. Now what is different for that perticular player?

Comment: This screenshot is not from the app.  It is a png  file. I am trying to reproduce this in Swift.  I am trying to search for a working example that shows how to overlay images.